# GLM functions not working

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-3, glm-math

I am trying to create a simply matrix to use in my shader (new to OpenGL 3.x), however, I am getting errors from GLM.

Here is one thing I tried doing:

```
glm::mat4 scaleMatrix = glm::scale(2.0f, 2.0f, 2.0f);
```

Unfortunately, the compiler (MinGW) gives me the error:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'scale(float, float, float)'
candiate is:
template<class T, glm::precision P> glm::detail::tmat4x4<T, P> glm::scale(const   
glm::detail::tmat4x4<T, P>&, const glm::detail::tvec3<T, P>&)
```

When I click on the error in the IDE it takes me to the first line below in "matrix_transform.inl":

```
GLM_FUNC_QUALIFIER detail::tmat4x4<T, P> scale
        (
        detail::tmat4x4<T, P> const & m,
        detail::tvec3<T, P> const & v
        )
```

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At least in the current version of [glm (0.9.6)](https://github.com/g-truc/glm) there is no glm::scale function taking three floats as argument. There is only one overload that takes a matrix which should be scaled a vector containing the scaling factors.

The correct solution for your code sample would ([according to here](http://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.6/code.html)) be

```
glm::mat4 scaleMatrix = glm::scale(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(2.0f, 2.0f, 2.0f));
```

Edit: I just stumbled over [this page](http://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.4/api/a00206.html), and it looks as if there has been a glm:scale(float,float,float) overload in 0.9.4.

Edit: As pointed out by sajas, there is a second overload of the glm::scale function available. This one would take only a glm::vec3 and might be more what you were looking for.

```
glm::mat4 scaleMatrix = glm::scale(glm::vec3(2.0f, 2.0f, 2.0f));
```